# What's the largest array that can exist in Swift?

Tags: swift

What is the most number of elements that an array in Swift would contain? Just a hypothetical question.

Comment: How long is a piece of string/How much RAM/Disk Space do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Well the subscript and the count property use Int. So that's your maximum. I assume `Int` is a 32 bit number, but perhaps it's 64 bit. So it wouldn't make sense to have an array any larger than you can count or index.

Actually, it's 32 bit or 64 bit depending on [platform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/NumericTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH18-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

The language does not necessarily decide how much elements an array can store. Because it's really a pointer to an array, you can always add more elements until you run out of RAM. With 4GB of RAM you can theoretically store 4 billion (roughly) chars, 1 billion ints, or 4 billion/(size of the stored element) of whatever you're storing. Essentially, it depends on your RAM.

However, as the other answer states, it would be impractical to have an array with more elements that the count method could return. That is, if you keep adding RAM, it does not necessarily follow that you will be able to store more (there is a cutoff). Being such, a quick way to check what happens in the compiler is to init an `NSMutableArray` with a capacity of your choice. Going too high gives the error, "Integer constant is larger than the largest unsigned integer type". A search through the Apple Docs shows that the maximum int that can be stored, a UInt64, is 18446744073709551615. In fact, try to initialize an array with the capacity of just one more, and you will get the error message. The only dilemma, now, is if you want to consider the potential that the array can store more elements than you can retrieve, which i'm sure is impossible but can't verify. Either way, it would then defeat the purpose of the array itself.

Comment: Muteable implies that you can silence it; it's actually "mutable", meaning that you can turn its turtles into mutants.